# how to auto scroll page when validation is true in flutter

Tags: validation, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I want to auto-scroll page when validation is true. suppose my page has many fields which not fit in a screen that's why I used a scroll view. but I want automatic scroll if any field is empty or validation is true. it will automatically show to the user using a scroll that this field is empty.

Comment: Have you tried settings focus to specific field where you want to scroll

Comment: I want auto scroll on the checkbox of terms and condition when user doesn't select that box ir will scroll to the terms and condition

Comment: if i understand correctly, you should use `ScrollController` and pass it to your scrollable widget as `controller` and scroll to your checkbox when condition was false. so use `animateTo()` or `jumpTo()` method for moving to checkbox position.

Comment: okay i'll try and let you know

Comment: @MohammadMeshkani checkbox doesn't have the controller property

Comment: you should put all off widgets in listview

Comment: yes all step i've done as you say.

But can you please tell me how i redirect to particular error widget

Comment: did you find a solution to that? I'm stack in

Comment: didnt get any proper solution till now

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on how to make a auto scroll but try adding `FocusNodes` to your `TextFormFields`

```
final focus = FocusNode();

TextFormField(
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              autofocus: true,
              onFieldSubmitted: (v){
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focus);
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              focusNode: focus,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Input 2"),
            ),
```

Comment: i want auto scroll for terms and condition checkbox

 i want auto scroll on the checkbox of terms and condition when user doesn't select that box it will scroll to the terms and condition